# Free Hyperlink Matrix

Tags: matlab, pagerank

I am studying Google PageRank, and require a large (1000x1000 or more) hyperlink matrix to implement in my MATLAB code. I could use random data but this is unlikely to give me good results.

Is there anywhere on the web where I can find free hyperlink matrices? Unsurprisingly, Google don't publish theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely an answer to your question, but MATLAB's original author Cleve Moler has [this book chapter](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/exm/chapters/pagerank.pdf) all about pagerank in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

TREC:

- http://trec.nist.gov/data/webmain.html
- http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/test_collections/

About the data:

- [Do TREC Web Collections Look Like the Web?](http://www.sigir.org/forum/F2002/soboroff.pdf)